Lifting matrix units from Calkin algebra
My question is about Examples 15.4.2(b) of Blackadar “K-Theory for Operator Algebras”.
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $Q(H) = B(H)/K(H)$ be the Calkin algebra. Given a *-homomorphism $\tau: M_n(\mathbb{C}) \to Q(H)$, the author claims that $\tau$ can be lifted to $B(H)$ (namely, there exists a *-homomorphism $\tilde{\tau}: M_n(\mathbb{C}) \to B(H)$ satisfying $\tau = \pi \circ \tilde{\tau}$, where $\pi$ denotes the canonical homomorphism $B(H) \to Q(H)$) as follows.
First, we lift each $\tau(E_{ii})$ to a projection $p_{ii} \in B(H)$. Let $w_i \in B(H)$ with $\pi(w_i) = \tau(E_{1i})$ and let $e_{1i}\in B(H)$ be the partial isometry in the polar decomposition of $p_{11}w_ip_{ii} \in B(H)$. Then we have $\pi(e_{1i}) = \tau(E_{1i}), e_{1i}^* e_{1i} \leq p_{ii}$ and $e_{1i}e_{1i}^* \leq p_{11}$. The map $\tilde{\tau}: M_n(\mathbb{C}) \to B(H)$ defined by $\tilde{\tau}(E_{ij}) = e_{1i}^* e_{1j}$ is a desired lift of $\tau$.
I understand the construction of $\tilde{\tau}$, but I do not see why $\tilde{\tau}$ is a *-homomorphism, or more specifically, why $\tilde{\tau}$ preserves products. 【EDIT: In general $\tilde{\tau}$ does not preserve products. See the answer by David Gao.】
By linearity, what we have to show is $\tilde{\tau}(E_{ij}E_{kl}) = \tilde{\tau} (E_{ij}) \tilde{\tau} (E_{kl})$. This amounts to showing $e_{1i}^*e_{1j}e_{1k}^*e_{1l} = \delta_{jk}e_{1i}^*e_{1l}$. The case $j=k$ is fine since we have $e_{1i}e_{1i}^* \leq p_{11}$ and $e_{1j}e_{1j}^* \leq p_{11}$. 【EDIT: This is wrong. Even the case $j=k$ is not fine. See the answer by David Gao.】However, I do not know how to handle the case where $j \neq k$.
Since $e_{1j} = e_{1j}p_{jj}$ and $e_{1k}^* = p_{kk}e_{1k}^*$, I think it suffices for the case $j \neq k$ if we can take each projection $p_{ii} ∈ B(H)$ so that $p_{ii}p_{jj} = 0$ for $i ≠ j$. But I am not sure if such a choice of $p_{ii}$ is allowed.
Thank you for your help.
(For the existence of $p_{ii}$, see Does the fiber of a projection, under a surjective *-homomorphism, contain a projection? .)

Even for $j = k$ this construction does not work as is. Let $H = \ell^2$, $S$ be the unilateral shift, $P_e$ be the projection onto even coordinates, and $P_o$ be the projection onto odd coordinates. Then $\tau’: M_2(\mathbb{C}) \to B(H)$, $\tau’(E_{11}) = P_e$, $\tau’(E_{12}) = SP_o$, $\tau’(E_{21}) = P_oS^\ast$, and $\tau’(E_{22}) = P_o$ define a $\ast$-homomorphism, and $\tau = \pi \circ \tau’: M_2(\mathbb{C}) \to Q(H)$ is thus a $\ast$-homomorphism.
Now, following the construction, we may choose $p_{ii} = \tau’(E_{ii})$ for $i = 1, 2$. We also choose $w_1 = p_{11}$. Note that this implies $p_{11}w_1p_{11} = p_{11}$ is a projection, so $e_{11} = p_{11} = P_e$. For $w_2$, we will not choose $\tau’(E_{12})$. Instead, we choose $w_2 = SP_oP_{[3, \infty)}$, where $P_{[3, \infty)}$ denote the projection onto all coordinates with indices larger than or equal to $3$. Since $P_{[3, \infty)}$ is co-finite dimensional, $\pi(w_2) = \tau(E_{12})$ is still true. As $p_{11}w_2p_{22} = w_2$ is already a partial isometry, we have $e_{12} = w_2$. Then $\tilde{\tau}(E_{11}) = e^\ast_{11}e_{11} = P_e$, $\tilde{\tau}(E_{12}) = e_{11}^\ast e_{12} = P_eSP_oP_{[3, \infty)} = SP_oP_{[3, \infty)}$, $\tilde{\tau}(E_{21}) = e_{12}^\ast e_{11} = P_{[3, \infty)}P_oS^\ast P_e = P_{[3, \infty)}P_oS^\ast$, so,
$$P_e = \tilde{\tau}(E_{11}) \neq \tilde{\tau}(E_{12})\tilde{\tau}(E_{21}) = SP_oP_{[3, \infty)}S^\ast$$
as the LHS sends $e_2$ to $e_2$ but the RHS sends $e_2$ to $0$.
